# How to view video in html5 tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

I would like to ask question about how to play a video on my browser. When I try to load my video file to my browser it displays nothing. My teacher said that maybe it is because the browser is not supported by html5.

What is your idea guys. I am hoping for your positive response.

Comment: What's your browser and code language (asp.net, html...)?

Comment: What do you mean "it displays nothing" - it's shows some black rectangle, empty video, etc.. You should start with http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: [Simply read the documents on the video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
Video courtesy of 
<a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body>
```

please Refer This pages

[SEE THE PAGE](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=JfADA2vg-AN)

Comment: I already tried this ivin raj but still not working, anyway thank you for your idea.

Comment: it's ok sir @junerd am also trying better answer coming soon for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Hav you tried to use it by 
video tag,

```
<video id="samp" src="sampvideo.mov" controls> </video>
```

this should it work

Comment: Hav you tried to use it by <video tag,

<video id="samp" src="sampvideo.mov" controls> </video>
thanks, samrat sarkar,
coderstutorial.blogspot.com

Comment: Just try to use src directive inside video tag

Answer (score 0):

If your teacher say your browser doesn't support html5.

Try double check in your browser eg. if you using chrome

Go to Menu --> Setting --> About and if it say need to be updated then click update.

Chrome support with html5 tag. Really weird if it not.

More info can check here https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html

[image]

For the coding part

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

It work and i already do a test here the display

[image]